# How can I install Ubuntu onto a external HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on external hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43174/installing-ubuntu-on-external-hard-disk)

I have got an external hard drive and want to install Ubuntu onto it.

How can I do this? The external HDD is a 'Western Digital my passport'
It says that it needs to be formatted for a Linux installation.