# Help with increasing available space when using Live USB

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I am trying to use Ubuntu temporarily. I am using a live USB for that. It is a 32 GB pendrive. When I am using Ubuntu through live USB, and when I try to install any programs, it says the space is running out.

But, when I switch to Windows, the flash drive still has 24 GB of space left.

How do I make my live USB use the space left in the pendrive.  I am **not** interested in anything being persistent, just that the I have more room to install application while using the Live USB.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/natuq.jpg link for Storgae of USB

Comment: What program did you use to install Ubuntu to the Live USB? Startup Disk Creator now installs the OS to a read only ISO9660 partition and leaves no read/write space. UNetbootin can make a Persistent Live USB with maximum 4GB persistence for the installation of new programs. Mkusb can build a drive with an unlimited persistent partition and also a storage partition that can be used by both Windows and Linux. The drive needs to be persistent if you want installed programs to persist between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to why you'd want the ability to install enough software to stretch the 4Gb limit of the standard pendrive Live, but then not want to use persistence.  You'll have to reinstall all the software each time you reboot.

However - I would suggest that persistence is the best way to give yourself that extra room.

A Casper-RW persistence file is limited to 4Gb due to the FAT32 4Gb file size limit - so you might want to try a persistent partition if you need more.

[The answers to this question will be helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664577/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-live-usb-flash-drive-with-casper-rw-persistent-partition/878009#878009) : [Unable to boot Ubuntu Live USB Flash Drive with casper-rw persistent partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664577/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-live-usb-flash-drive-with-casper-rw-persistent-partition/878009#878009)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for persistence or a full install? If full install, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163982/run-12-04-from-usb-with-no-hard-disk-usage)

Comment: i dont want persistence in this context, when i boot with my live usb, I should be able to install programs which i need  and use usb optimally.. Not interested with persistence now, i am concerned with optimal usage of space.

Comment: Have you checked the partition sizes on the drive? Also, could you provide a little more info on your setup? I think I may have misunderstood your situation. Is your live USB the ubuntu installer iso written to the drive, or a full install of ubuntu onto a drive?

Comment: I have given image of my live usb storage .. please see it

Answer (score 0):

While it would take a substantially more work than creating a persistent USB you would have to create a [LiveCDCustomized Media](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).  The link is for a starting point so that you can see some of what is involved.

The default LiveUSB is designed to allow the user to easily Try Ubuntu, but it's main design is for the installation, and of course, having a variety of drivers for different computer's hardware.

You could spend some time in the environment of the Live Session, mounting  the space you see and moving files around to the other space, as well as other drives of your computer.  But that will take a substantially lot of work also.  Some of the things you might want to configure may require rebooting.  That would mean that when you reboot, you will have to start from scratch.

By design its not setup for the type of task you describe.  The space that you see available may eventually be used for the intended task as the Operating System and it's necessities grow with time.

**You can use the other space, but you would have to tedious manually map the space for usage** and move files from root `/` to the mapped space.  Then linked to them for access.

The unused/unmaped space isn't available by default and design.  You run out of space because the actual root `/` is in RAM, not the actual USB.

The purpose of the **persistence** that you don't want to use is to allow the root `/` system to be on the actual disk where the space is located.