# Booting from a USB for HP laptop

Tags: usb, hp

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu from my USB, but my laptop stays stuck at the black "hp" screen. I've tried tapping F9 to get to my boot menu, and even f10 to enter BIOS....but nothing seems to work. What should I do?

My notebook is an HP G61-429WM.
I purchased a new harddrive so there is no current OS.

update:

Found an OS disc for Vista, going to try and install onto my notebook.

Comment: Welcome Mari, Firstly have a look at this Q&A to identify you have prepared things correctly up to now.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/43174/installing-ubuntu-on-external-hard-disk

Comment: Thank you for the link. I would also like to add more info. I had to purchase a new internal harddrive yesterday because my previous one was damaged. I downloaded Ubuntu through my desktop and used "Universal USB Installer " to copy onto my USB. I'm going to read over the link you provided. Thank you.

Comment: @Mari-  set your BIOS setting to **defaults** and try again.

Comment: Still no luck. And installing Vista from the CD didn't work either. Is there probably something else wrong with my notebook?

Comment: according to http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00364979&tmp_task=useCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4125456 in addition to f10, you might want to try f2 or f6

Comment: is your problem still persists??

Answer (score 2):

Try to reset the BIOS by e.g. removing the CMOS battery and see if that works. It could also be defective RAM. I've had that if I had bad RAM the computer wouldn’t get past the BIOS loading screen.

Comment: There are also more ways to reset the BIOS. Most mainboard manufacturers implement a special reset key combination, for example to hold `PAGE-UP` while turning the power on.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Mari, BIOS key is mostly one of <kbd>F2</kbd> , <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, or <kbd>delete</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, mine is F10 for BIOS. The issue is that, whenever I insert my USB into a port and turn on my laptop, it stays stuck on the "hp" screen and does not go anywhere regardless of what key I tap. Thank you for the welcome.

Comment: Let me guess PNY?