# Saving changes when booting from USB drive 12.04 desktop

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded version 12.04 desktop then loaded on a USB so I can boot a Wyse thin client with no OS.  I can boot the device with the USB key and everything looks fine but when I open the remmina remote desktop client and enter the ip and other setting I can't get them to save after a reboot.  Same thing happens when I create a text document, I save it to a folder but after a reboot it's gone.

I am a newbie to this product and this may not be possible, please point me in the right direction of you can please.  Thanks,

Comment: A live Media does not save your settings , you need to install it on USB Drive [see here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43174/installing-ubuntu-on-external-hard-disk)

Comment: To save a text document or for that anything in ur home folder it must be possible, but I'm may not be sure about whatever changes u make to OS(in the filesystem)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, I hope this helps.

Hit Super(Windows Button) type in the following

[image]

Put in the USB Drive, Erase the disk, key in the location of the Ubuntu ISO Image

[image]

This is something that u should try >> Stored In Reserved Extra Space, Increase it to a few Gigs, depending on how much space u have to spare.

[image]

OR

If u want to do this from Windows, make use an application called Universal USB Installer.

[image]

Reserve some space to store ur files.

[image]