# Wubi doesn't start, with a "cannot mount /dev/dm-3" error

Tags: wubi, raid

I installed [Wubi](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/) here, but when restart the pc I got the following screen:

[image]

And this "command line" "initramfs". How do I preceed from here?

**--update**

By the way, looks like my HD is raid. Not sure, because I really don't know how to check, and don't know if this changes anything for using Wubi.

Comment: I'd start by uninstalling Wubi from Windows and try installing it again.

Comment: @izx I uninstalled, reboot, and re-installed, but got the same screen, unfortunately.

Comment: Just a little idea. I would check if the BIOS is configured to deny any software to write at the MBR, if so I would disable this protection and I would reinstall this program.

Comment: @Salvador I really don't want trouble with the MBR in my work's computer, I choose WUBI because it don't need to write the MBR.

Comment: I would follow the advice in your screenshot: reboot into windows, run `chkdsk /r`, reboot back into windows, etc.

Comment: @enzotib I did it, but I got the same screen.

Comment: That `chkdsk` message is generic. The problem appears to be the raid (`Mounting /dev/dm-3 ...: No such device`) so add the raid details to the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your problem is that [*Wubi is **not supported** on software RAID arrays*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Software_raid_arrays).

  - The error has nothing to do with NTFS. Wubi simply can't find the software raid volume `/dev/dm-3`.
  - Some users may get this to work on some systems, by building custom kernels, etc., but in general it's not a good idea.
- Note that Wubi NEVER writes to the MBR; it simply modifies the Windows bootloader configuration.
- With your software RAID, if you want to install Ubuntu *without* writing to the MBR, then you should do a normal Ubuntu install but towards the end, install the bootloader (GRUB) **on the partition** (i.e. NOT `/dev/sda`, but `/dev/sda3` or similar).

  - Then you can use EasyBCD (on Windows 7) to create a bootloader entry/stub from the Windows 7 startup menu to start your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you still can boot into windows then first install "EasyBCD 2.1.2" from softpedia.com. Go to BCD deployment tab, overwrite Windows 7 or XP boot-loader. Open "Add new entry" section. Open Linux/BSD tab. Click on type and select "Wubi" from there. Click on "Add entry".

   Go to BCD Deployment again and click on "Write MBR"

   Reboot.
2. If still the problem persists. Overwrite the boot-loader again. Delete all Ubuntu related files form system. (Use control panel to uninstall Ubuntu. Use "Ccleaner.exe" to clear any registry entries)

   Reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I really want to use Wubi to avoid writing on MBR (one of the reasons is that I want to avoid problems with RAID in my work's computer).

Answer (score 0):

Put in the live CD, go to the Disk Utility and see if all your partitions are fine. If there's nothing wrong, then try running

`e2fsck -v -f /dev/loop0`

It is not guaranteed to work first time so I recommend you refer to the relevant threads over at ubuntuforums.com.

Comment: I would like to know what this command does, as it's my work's computer (not mine). Could you explain?

Comment: just finds and fixes the damaged filesystem. You get initrams generally in the case of damaged filesystems and thats why i suggested this. although this can make you lose some data in some cases - never happened with me though -, but since you have just installed, thats not a problem really

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following in adding this

- You can still boot to windows
- You see the screen, as shown, when you choose Ubuntu from the
  bootloader menu.

Now as it is *almost* confirmed that you have a RAID array, on which `wubi` is not supported , as @izx has already pointed out, you have two options IMO.

1. Follow what izx has suggested.
2. Remove the wubi install, using any of the method listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation), esp try *bcdedit*  tool, if simple uninstall doesn't work.

If you prefer to proceed with the second option, you can still use ubuntu on your work's computer by [Installing Ubuntu on an external hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43174/installing-ubuntu-on-external-hard-disk) or a USB drive.

**Note : This is useful only if you cannot/don't wish to create a partition on the computer, but still want to use Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 0):

The initramfs propt comes because the system cannot write at boot. When you're in the grub menu, press 'e' to edit the commands before booting, and manually change the " ro " occurrences with " rw ". Then F10 to go.

When you (or the O.S.) upgrade the grub configuration, options are read only (ro). You have to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg (at least, this is the file in Ubuntu 15), changing "ro" to "rw" (read/write), in order to make it persistent (just until next grub update). Anyway, you should trigger a script to make changes at grub.cfg changes.