# Ubuntu 16.04.1 do not boot

Tags: boot, grub2

```
I Download ISO file of "Ubuntu 16"
Then I used it to create usb installation Media

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my External Hard Drive "WD Elements 10AB"
Everything is going OK & Installation is Successful
```

**But**

```
 When I Restart My PC its Stuck in
```

**Grub Rescue >** -_-

```
I started Live Ubuntu again from USB Drive & Used "Boat Repair"
I Follow the Instructions Exactly & the repair is Successful
```

**But** When I Restart again I stuck in **grub rescue >** again

I Tried Formatting The Flash Drive & My External Hard Drive , Then Start over But I get **the same Result** Every Time
-_-

Notes :
My Computer Specifications :
2 GB RAM
Intel Core 2Duo

my internal drivers are **disconnected** before Installation & I didn't Reconnect them **Never after** installation

The Report of "*Boot Repair*" is :
[Boot Repair Summary URL](http://paste2.org/dk28PLbz) 
Please **Help**

Answer (score 0):

See this:
[Installing Ubuntu on external hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43174/installing-ubuntu-on-external-hard-disk)

And this:
[How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

If set up properly, it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately , i did exactly these insructions for installing but nothing changed 

Comment: What if you simply use a live image and use that instead of installing? Even if only on a USB drive? Also, silly question, but is the boot order set to boot from USB first?